# Can the infimum of a set consisting only of nonnegative numbers be negative?

Tags: real-analysis

Can the infimum of a set consisting only of nonnegative numbers be negative?

I'm having trouble thinking of examples.

Comment: No because zero is a lower bound.

Comment: Imagine yes and the infimum is set to `a` (negative number), how would you then get passed `a/2` (also negative) if all members of your set are positive?

Answer (score 4):

No. The infimum is the *greatest lower bound*. If every $x$ in $E$ is non-negative, we have $x \ge 0$ for all $x$ in $E$. Thus $0$ is a lower bound for $E$. So $\inf E \ge 0$.